# Can I share/download a wishlist on Bricklink?

Tags: bricklink

I have a whole set in a wishlist in BrickLink and I would like to share it with some friends.

Can I either:

- Share the list via BrickLink so they can use it directly.
- Download it in XML so they can upload it to their wishlist.

If I can do them, how? If I can't, any alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Time have passed and things got changed on Bricklink. You can now open you wanted list on Bricklink and hit "Download" button as pictured below to get XML file that you can share.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is no built-in way to download the Bricklink wanted lists. However, there is a userscript that should work for this.

DISCLAIMER:  Use at your own risk. YMMV.

http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/167618

Firefox with [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-Us/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) is the way I use other user scripts, but I wasn't able to get this working with Firefox.  I was able to get it working with Chrome and [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en).

You'll want to make sure you read the description in the link above, and pay attention to the tips they recommend like increasing the number of items per page so you capture everything.